# Object with user-configurable property "visibility"

Tags: c#, oop, properties

I have a User object with a bunch of properties. I have a requirement that states when a user sets up their information, they need the ability to state which properties of their profile are visible to others.

The way I had envisioned this was adding an additional property - a list of string that would contain the property names that were publicly visible. I could then implement a method called ToPublicView() or something similar that would use reflection to set non-public properties to null or default.

Is this a reasonable approach, or is there a better way?

Comment: I think it's the simplest of the options. If reflection start to kill your performance, you may want to have a dictionary of property-delegate for accessing the values.

Comment: What? It's a crazy, crazy, crazy option.

Comment: Why? The requirement is not to have dynamic properties, so it doesn't make sense to have all the properties in a dynamic way. Also, having them as actual properties will make the code more readable when you have to use it for the rest of the application.

Comment: The *business requirement* is not directly related to the code you actually write. It would get a bit crazy if it were, wouldn't it?

Comment: Glad to see everyone agrees ;) I like the idea of Property objects, but I'm still not sure of the exact reason behind the strongly worded objection ("crazy, crazy, crazy"). I'd just like to know what the _reasons_ are because the original idea is still appealing to me.

Comment: I decided on sticking with my original idea. The class stays simple, and performance is not an issue. I'm not sure why it was panned so badly. Creation of a new User, setting properties, creating another new User and copying selected properties using reflection occurs 80000/sec on my laptop, and I don't expect it to happen more than a few times a day per tenant. @ivowiblo if you post your reply as an answer I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's the simplest of the options. If reflection start to kill your performance, you may want to have a dictionary of property-delegate for accessing the values.

And as the requirement is not to have dynamic properties but just to mark the existing ones, it doesn't make sense to have all the properties in a dynamic way (like a list of property objects). Also, having them as actual properties will make the code more readable when you have to use it for the rest of the application.

Answer (score 1):

In such a situation, if possible, I would suggest simply having a list of your properties, such as:

```
public Class Property<T>
{
    public Property(string name, bool visible, T value)
    {
        Name = name;
        Visible = visible;
        Value = value;
    }

    string Name { get; set; }
    bool Visible { get; set; }
    T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could create a list of the properties like this:

```
List<Property> properties = new List<Property>();
properties.Add(new Property<string>("FirstName", true, "Steve"));
```

If you need to be able to set the visibility today, you may need to set other meta-properties as well tomorrow.  Color?  Required/Optional?  Size?  Etc.  Having your own Property type allows you to easily expand it in the future.

Comment: Except that I guess you should use some sort of enum for the Visible property, make the name strongly immutable (define it as readonly), and add an interface for generic variance (contra- con- whatever). At least. You'd store an enumerable like IEnumerable<IProperty<object>> or maybe define a separate IProperty object that's a super to IProperty<T>

Comment: Super over architectured/complicated.

Comment: I didn't say that this was the best situation in every scenario.  Without more specifics about the poster's exact situation, it's hard to say for sure.  But, in many cases, I think this would be the best solution.  However, I can easily imagine (since I've run into them in my own experience) situations where you don't want a dynamic list like this, you want actual properties.  That's why I said "if possible".  I thought it was worth mentioning this as an option in case it does fit the poster's needs or any other readers in days to come.

Answer (score 0):

What? No. If that's the demand, then User properties should *not* be realized with actual properties, but instead using some sort of IEnumerable and Property objects, where each Property has its visibility, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Can use, may be, some combination of custom [DynamicObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx) implementation

**EDIT**

```
  //custom property class
  public class MyProperty
  {
      public bool IsVisible { get; set; }
      public string PropertyName { get; set; }
  }

  public class Dymo: DynamicObject
  {

      Dictionary<MyProperty, object> dictionary
          = new Dictionary<MyProperty, object>();

      public override bool TryGetMember(
          GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
      {
          result = false;
          var prop = PropertyFromName(binder.Name);
          if (prop != null && prop.IsVisible)
              return dictionary.TryGetValue(prop, out result);

          return false;

      }

      public override bool TrySetMember(
          SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
      {

          var prop = PropertyFromName(binder.Name);
          if (prop != null && prop.IsVisible)
              dictionary[prop] = value;
          else
              dictionary[new MyProperty { IsVisible = true, PropertyName = binder.Name}] = value;
          return true;
      }

      private MyProperty PropertyFromName(string name)
      {
          return (from key in dictionary.Keys where key.PropertyName.Equals(name) select key).SingleOrDefault<MyProperty>();
      }


      public void SetPropertyVisibility(string propertyName, bool visibility)
      {
          var prop = PropertyFromName(propertyName);
          if (prop != null)
              prop.IsVisible = visibility;         
      }
  }
```

and use this, after like this.

```
dynamic dynObj = new Dymo();
dynObj.Cartoon= "Mickey" ;
dynObj.SetPropertyVisibility("Mickey", false); //MAKE A PROPERTY "INVISIBLE"
```

Comment: ouch, just imagining something like this in code I get to maintain hurts my brain.

Comment: @erikkallen: your brain can not be a reason for downvote, sorry. If you can find some **real** reason, you're welcome. It's easy and clear solution, don't see anything complicated here. And by the way, this is just an example (yet working one), that can be optimized to fit the needs of the OP.

Comment: I don't think it's a bad solution, but I have a need for a stronger/less dynamic type. It's something to keep in mind in the future for me, for sure.